# What is wrong with this PL/SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, ora-00979

I am working with PL/SQL (Oracle).
I have written queries before, but I'm not sure what is wrong with this query.  The error I am getting is this:

> [Error] Execution (942: 41):
>   ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

The highlighted text is: the first TRIM function in the case statement.  I know that I can't put this case statement in the Group By clause because I am aggregating here (using the sum function).  Is there something I am not understanding??

```
SELECT 
T.PLANNAME, 
M.CLASS, 
M.BRAND_OR_GENERIC, 
T.PROCEDURECODE, 
M.BRAND_NAME, 
M.GENERIC_NAME, 
CASE 
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) = 'XXXX' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'COMMERCIAL') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/160000)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) = 'XXXX' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'MEDICARE') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/14000)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) = 'YYYY' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'COMMERCIAL') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/1800000)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) = 'YYYY' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'MEDICARE') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/35000)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) LIKE 'ZZZZ%' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'COMMERCIAL') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/1200462)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) LIKE 'ZZZZ%' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'MEDICARE') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/235000)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) = 'AAAA' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'COMMERCIAL') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/200000)*1000000, 2)
WHEN (TRIM(PLANNAME) = 'BBBB' AND TRIM(LOBDESC) = 'MEDICAID') THEN ROUND((SUM(ALLOWEDAMT)/147000)*1000000, 2)
END As AllowedPerMM,
SUM(T.ALLOWEDAMT) As SumOfALLOWEDAMT 


FROM FIN.TR_2011 T
LEFT JOIN FIN.TR_REFERENCE M ON T.PROCEDURECODE = M.PROCEDURECODE

WHERE 
T.PROCEDURECODE IS NOT NULL AND  
(T.PROCEDURECODE <> '0' or T.PROCEDURECODE <> 0)  AND 

(T.PROCEDURECODE Like 'J%' OR 
T.PROCEDURECODE Like 'C9%' OR
T.PROCEDURECODE Like 'S0%' OR
T.PROCEDURECODE Like 'Q%' OR 
T.PROCEDURECODE = '90378' OR 
T.PROCEDURECODE IN ( 
'J9171', 'J9265', 'J9264', 
'J2430', 'J3487',
'J9000', 'J9001') OR
M.THERAPEUTIC_CLASS IN ('RA')
) AND 
TRIM(T.YEAR) IN ('2010')

GROUP BY 
T.PLANNAME, 
M.CLASS, 
M.BRAND_OR_GENERIC, 
T.PROCEDURECODE, 
M.BRAND_NAME, 
M.GENERIC_NAME

ORDER BY SumOfALLOWEDAMT DESC ;
```

Comment: The oracle documentation includes a whole book devoted to explaining the Error Messages.  Find it here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a non aggragate (`LOBDESC`) in a grouping context. You have two options, choose the one which makes most sense:

- Add `LOBDESC` to `GROUP BY`
- Use an aggregate function, i.e. `MAX(LOBDESC)`

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle, when grouping, you can only select either:

- Fields appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause
- Aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc) on other fields

Your `CASE` clause will have be rewritten. Probably, you will be better off by using analytic functions for your purpose:

http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html

Comment: When adding the case statement to the Group By, it highlights the text sum in the case statement and gives the error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Comment: @JK: Yes, I just thought of that. You're using a `SUM` there, that can't be grouped

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `LOBDESC` to the `GROUP BY` columns list because you're using it in the `select` outside of an agregation function.